# Django ORM - filtering on related objects

Tags: python, django, performance, orm

Let's suppose I have a model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to query all users and have list of today's posts for each of them.

Here are some good solutions, for example using model methods or iterating through each User, but it seems to me that they do not really have a good performance, because ORM is not used by them.
Maybe there is any way like `User.objects.all().annotate(filtered_posts = ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to query by "today's posts" but I see no datetime field so I'll assume one. Additionally you'll need to change the related name (it describes the name looking from the other models perspective so: `related_name='posts'` would be more appropriate).

You can access related objects when querying by `__` for e.g.

```
User.objects.filter(posts__created=time)
```

This will return a queryset of users that have posts created today.

Note that `time` variable I used as an example is another thing to cover. For example you may want to use `posts__created_at__range` to provide a 2 element tuple of today midnight to tomorrow midnight.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I messed a bit with related name and forgot about date field. I have fixed it now.

But you have not correctly understood me. I don't want to filter users by date, but i need to serialize User objects with posts filtered by date.

Comment: Have you tried the code I wrote? I think it will do exactly what you are describing - will return `Users` whose posts where created at a specific `create` date. Filtering `Users` by date as you said would go by `User.objects.filter(created=time)` and I used `posts__created=time` in my example. If I'm wrong here I will have to ask you to rephrase the question.